# Cannot resolve Base64.encodeToString

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to save images on firebase using code below.

```
  Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgDecodableString);
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100,baos);
  byte[] byteArray =  baos.toByteArray();
  String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray,Base64.DEFAULT);
```

But i am facing an error :

```
cannot resolve method 'encodeToString(byte[],?)' 
cannot resolve symbol 'DEFAULT'
```

How to fix this error.

Comment: You have the wrong `Base64` class imported. It should be `android.util.Base64`, not `org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64`.

Comment: Is your problem solved ??

Comment: Now i get it to work . I was importing the wrong class.

Comment: whats the wright answer then facing same problem

Comment: Yogesh Borhade, Now there is no need to use base64 string now firebase have launched very easy and effective solution for saving images and multimedia files name Firebase Storage please go to firebase.google.com and checkout docs section.Hopefully your problem will resolve.

Answer (score 15):

I think you have import *org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64* in your file, please re-check and instead try using import **android.util.Base64**. It will resolve your problem for **cannot resolve method 'encodeToString(byte[],?)'**.

Comment: Yes now it is working fine.   Do you have any idea of how to retrieve images using getter method in firebase list Adapter.

Answer (score 5):

Try it:

```
val encodedImage = encodeToString(b, DEFAULT)
```

Comment: Yep this works for Kotlin